# Testing particular value of correlation / covariance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, covariance

I'm writing code for a Monte Carlo simulation and I know that a particular subset of generated values should be independent identically, normally distributed with covariance have a fixed covariance matrix, say: $$\Sigma = \left(\begin{matrix}1&1/2\\1/2&1/3\end{matrix}\right)$$

I'm interested in testing whether the simulation conforms to the exact solution by testing the $1/2$ value in such covariance matrix.

I've seen some tests to verify that two samples have the same covariance, how to test that a sample has a a priori known covariance value however?

(Sample size is not an issue, I can have $N=10^6$ samples or more if necessary)

Comment: This sounds like some kind of two one-sided tests (TOST). You’ll have to allow for some tolerance. Covariance to be not equal to $1/2$, though, like $0.50000012705$ being “close enough”.

Comment: @Dave I'm looking for a well established procedure. I'd like to understand if $0.50001$ is "close enough" or $0.50000001$ is "close enough" for a given number of samples. Surely someone researched this before me and I don't want to reinvent the wheel - I just don't know the right keywords to search for.

Comment: Which is close enough for you? That’s a decision for you to make. Statistics can’t tell you what you find interesting.

Comment: @Dave Surely the answer depends on the number of samples. I'd like a number of samples independent criterion. For example one that would have 5% Type I error rate.

Comment: You could use a likelihood-ratio test

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Is there a closed from formula for the cutoffs or a well known lookup table?

Comment: @Radost: Probably not, you could try the asymptotics or simulations

Comment: I was hoping that a simulation would not be verified by another simulation :(